# Conversion of .gho to AWS image

Tags: conversion, amazon-web-services, norton-ghost

I'm a training manager at a GIS software company.  I work with a 3rd party company who delivers our training through .gho images.  We are now looking to diversify, and offer AWS hosted training also.  Does anyone know how I can convert a .gho to an AWS?  Any help appreciated, as I would like to avoid building these complicated computer images twice.

Answer (score 0):

Create either a VMware or VirtualBox image. This can be converted into an EC2 AMI image and use this custom AMI when creating the new instance.
Try this [VM Import](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/) and this documentation in detail [EC2 VM Import Connector for VMware vCenter](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-EC2/2759763385083070)